# Move columns of smaller divs to the right and bottom as new rows of larger divs are added

Tags: html, css, pug

I am trying to use jade/pug and CSS to dynamically add a row of large divs from left to right, then push columns containing smaller columns of rows to the right and below. I'm certain that my issue lies with a lack of understanding of flex grids and CSS, so the fact that I'm using jade/pug is probably not as important as how I'm attempting to use divs/nesting and CSS...

I want to accomplish this:

1. New orange divs are added, so green div and all maroon ones are moved over and down.

[image]

2. The result should be like this:

[image]

What I'm ending up with using the following CSS...

```
div.top-stories{
   display: flex;
   flex-wrap: column wrap;
   flex-direction: row;
}
div.top-articles{
    width:350px;
    border-bottom:5px solid lightgrey;
    border-left:1px dotted lightgrey;
}

div.stories{
   display: flex;
   flex-wrap: wrap;
   flex-direction: row;
}
div.articles{
    width:350px;
    border-bottom:3px solid lightgrey;
    border-left:1px dotted lightgrey;
}
```

... and the following jade/pug code ...

```
    div.top-stories
        div.top-articles.w3-panel.w3-margin
            h2= headline
            h4= content
        div.top-articles.w3-panel.w3-margin
            h2= headline
            h4= content
    div.stories
        div.articles.w3-panel.w3-margin
            p= content
        div.articles.w3-panel.w3-margin
            p= content
        div.articles.w3-panel.w3-margin
            p= content
        div.articles.w3-panel.w3-margin
            p= content
        div.articles.w3-panel.w3-margin
            p= content
        div.articles.w3-panel.w3-margin
            p= content
        div.articles.w3-panel.w3-margin
            p= content
        div.articles.w3-panel.w3-margin
            p= content
```

... is this:

[image]

Note: I am using w3-css, which is why I have w3-classes added to the pug elements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope I have understood your question correctly...

Here is a possible layout using CSS Grid. Add and subtract large boxes to check whether it's suitable for your use case.

[codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/PRvGEZ?editors=1100)

```
.grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, 350px);
  grid-template-rows: repeat(auto-fill, 50px);
  grid-gap: 10px;
}
```

Basically, I've declared a grid that will create as many `350px`-wide columns that will fit in the viewport. I've also explicitly set the row height to be the height of a small box.

In your case, if you want the height of a large box to be equivalent to 6 small boxes you can use this formula:

((number of small boxes) * (height of small box)) + (grid gap * (number of small boxes-1))

(6 * 50px) + (10px * 5) = 350px

You can easily adjust this layout and make it more responsive by replacing `px` units with `%`, `auto`, `fr` or viewport units.

```css
.grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, 350px);
  grid-template-rows: repeat(auto-fill, 50px);
  grid-gap: 10px;
}

.big {
  background: orange;
  height: 350px; 
  grid-row: span 6;
}

.big + .small {
  background: green;
}

.small {
  height: 50px;
  background: pink;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
  <div class="big"></div>
  <div class="big"></div>
  <div class="big"></div>
  <div class="small"></div>
  <div class="small"></div>
  <div class="small"></div>
  <div class="small"></div>
  <div class="small"></div>
  <div class="small"></div>
  <div class="small"></div>
  <div class="small"></div>
  <div class="small"></div>
  <div class="small"></div>
  <div class="small"></div>
  <div class="small"></div>
  <div class="small"></div>
  <div class="small"></div>
  <div class="small"></div>
  <div class="small"></div>
  <div class="small"></div>
  <div class="small"></div>
  <div class="small"></div>
  <div class="small"></div>
  <div class="small"></div>
  
</div>
```

Comment: This appears to be precisely what I am looking for... Let me give it a shot within the context of pug and the variable content length I'm working with and I'll upvote / accept! Thank you

Comment: Great, get back to me if you run into any difficulties